# Mobile site: title shrink or background image re-size

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, header

I'm using a wordpress theme and i'm having difficulty with the mobile render. The company who owns the site (mythemeshop) are currently unresponsive to my question.

The image slider at the top of the page has a title component. When looking at it on a mobile the title gets pushed past the image (because of the font size and maybe some other things that i'm not aware of).

I'm just wondering what I should do here - I'm not sure how to

Our site is similar to the site expert360.com - it renders well for the mobile. You can see how they have a larger header image for their mobile site.

Our site is coequity.com.au

It seems when I make changes to the css that work for the mobile site, it' looks bad on the desktop site.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: to make changes that only affect mobile devices, use media queries: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for example make the text smaller on mobile devices using viewport sizing, if you don't want to touch the image:

```
@media (max-width: 568px) {
    #homepage_slider .flex-caption h2 {
        font-size: 2vh !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this comment and the one from @Sirence led me to change the image size: `code` @media only screen and (max-device-width: 568px) {
    div[class="has_caption"] img {
        height: 160px !important;
    }
}

Comment: I am @Sirence :( If it helped you, please mark it as the answer so the question is closed.